# Creating new column with values of looping through SparkSQL Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have sparkSQL Dataframe which contains unique code, monthdate and number of turnover. I want to loop over each monthdate to get the sum of the turnover in 12 months for turnover_per_year. For example if the monthdate is January 2022 then the sum will be from January 2021 to January 2022.
For example if i have data in 2021 and 2022. The calculation of `turnover_per_year in january 1st 2022 = turnover Jan 2021+ turnover feb 2021 + turnover march 2021 + ... + turnover dec 2021 + turnover jan 2022` but if i want to get the turnover_per_year in January 2021 then it will be null because i don't have the data in 2020.

This is the sample of the dataframe

```
+------+------------+----------+
| code | monthdate  | turnover |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-01-01 | 10       |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-02-01 | 20       |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-03-01 | 30       |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-04-01 | 40       |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-05-01 | 50       |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-06-01 | 60       |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-07-01 | 70       |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-08-01 | 80       |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-09-01 | 90       |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-10-01 | 100      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-11-01 | 101      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2021-12-01 | 102      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-01-01 | 103      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-02-01 | 104      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-03-01 | 105      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-04-01 | 106      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-05-01 | 107      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-06-01 | 108      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-07-01 | 109      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-08-01 | 110      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-09-01 | 111      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-10-01 | 112      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-11-01 | 113      |
+------+------------+----------+
| AA1  | 2022-12-01 | 114      |
+------+------------+----------+
```

I'm very new to spark and scala and it's confusing for me to solve this in spark scala way. I have developed the logic but have difficulties to translate it to spark scala. I'm working on cluster mode. Here's my logic.

```
listkey = df.select("code").distinct.map(r => r(0)).collect())
listkey.foreach(key=>
     df.select(*).filter("code==${key}").oderBy("monthdate").foreach(
        row=>
        var monthdate = row.monthdate
        var turnover = row.turnover
        var sum = 0
        sum = sum + turnover
        var n = 1
        var i = 1
        while (n<12){
               var monthdate_temp = datetime-i
               var turnover_temp =
               df.select("turnover").filter("monthdate=${monthdate_temp} and code =${key}").collect()
               sum = sum+turnover_temp
               n =n+1
               i = i+1
         }
         row = row.withColumn("turnover_per_year",sum)
    )
)
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each row in original dataframe can be expanded to 12 rows with back dates by "explode" function, and result joined with original dataframe, and grouped:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("AA1", "2021-01-01", 25),
  ("AA1", "2022-01-01", 103)
)
  .toDF("code", "monthdate", "turnover")
  .withColumn("monthdate", to_date($"monthdate", "yyyy-MM-dd"))

val oneYearBackMonths = (0 to 12).map(n => lit(-n))

val explodedWithBackMonths = df
  .withColumn("shift", explode(array(oneYearBackMonths: _*)))
  .withColumn("rangeMonth",expr("add_months(monthdate, shift)"))

val joinCondition = $"exploded.code" === $"original.code" &&
  $"exploded.rangeMonth" === $"original.monthdate"

explodedWithBackMonths.alias("exploded")
  .join(df.alias("original"), joinCondition)
  .groupBy($"exploded.code", $"exploded.monthdate")
  .agg(sum($"original.turnover").alias("oneYearTurnover"))
```

Result:

```
+----+----------+---------------+
|code|monthdate |oneYearTurnover|
+----+----------+---------------+
|AA1 |2021-01-01|25             |
|AA1 |2022-01-01|128            |
+----+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: error type mismatch on `.withColumn("rangeMonth", add_months($"monthdate", $"shift"))` required int, found column name, if i add `col( shift)` mismatch because its type is column

Comment: "add_months" added "Since: 3.0.0"

Comment: yes, my version is above 3.0.0 but somehow the function only receives literal integer, not by column, i tried replace shift with random number its able to add the months

Comment: variable "explodedWithBackMonths" was updated with "expr", please check.

Comment: the result is not what i expected, somehow data in 2019/1/1 has sum, it shouldn't have any sum at all because there's no data in 2018/1/1. because the calculation should be january 2018 + february 2018 +  ... + january 2019

Comment: it's hard to believe

Answer (score 1):

you can use Spark's Window function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val raw = Seq(
  ("AA1", "2019-01-01", 25),
  ("AA1", "2021-01-01", 25),
  ("AA1","2021-08-01",80),
  ("AA1" ,"2021-09-01" , 90 ),
  ("AA1", "2022-01-01", 103),
  ("AA2", "2022-01-01", 10)
).toDF("code", "monthdate", "turnover")
val df = raw.withColumn("monthdate",to_timestamp($"monthdate","yyyy-mm-dd"))
val pw = Window.partitionBy($"code").orderBy($"monthdate".cast("long")).rangeBetween(-(86400*365), 0)
df.withColumn("sum",sum($"turnover").over(pw)).show()

+----+-------------------+--------+---+
|code|          monthdate|turnover|sum|
+----+-------------------+--------+---+
| AA1|2019-01-01 00:01:00|      25| 25|
| AA1|2021-01-01 00:01:00|      25| 25|
| AA1|2021-01-01 00:08:00|      80|105|
| AA1|2021-01-01 00:09:00|      90|195|
| AA1|2022-01-01 00:01:00|     103|298|
| AA2|2022-01-01 00:01:00|      10| 10|
+----+-------------------+--------+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I created 2 window functions for testing, can you please check this and comment whether this is fine.

```
val w = Window.partitionBy($"code")
  .orderBy($"rownum")
  .rowsBetween(-11, Window.currentRow)
val w1  = Window.partitionBy($"code")
  .orderBy($"monthdate")
val newDf = initDf.withColumn("rownum", row_number().over(w1))
            .withColumn("csum",sum("turnover").over(w))
```

> We may need to first group by Month & Year and take the sum of the
> turnover for that month, then sort by month for that code

Comment: this will fail if the difference between rows > year and the data is not full (ie. there arent't 12 rows for each year)